# Confusion about jump discontinuity and Green's function of a B.V.P.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, greens-function

> What is the jump of a function with discontinuity of first kind?

I know that the jump of $f(x)$ is difference between left-hand-limit and right-hand-limit in modulus. That is

$$jump =|\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)|...(1)$$

Is it TRUE? $$OR$$ $$jump =\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)....(2)$$is TRUE ?

I know that $(1)$ is TRUE. But I am confused on it and my confusion arise from **Green's function** . Consider the 2nd order B.V.P. as:  $p_0(x)y''(x)+q(x)y(x)=f(x)$ , with some boundary conditions.

Then we know that the Green's function $G(x,t)$ is continuous and $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$ is discontinuous of 1st kind at $x=t$ with jump is given by  $$-\frac{1}{p_0(t)}$$

> If jump is non-negative then from where negative sign comes?

Please help...which definition is correct?

Comment: When working with Green's functions, your jumps are defined by your eq. (2) and have sign.

Comment: Why??????????????

Comment: Two points. First, if you are using (2) you do not need the minus sign ahead of $1/p_0(x)$. Second, the properties of the Green's function can be derived from the definition and properties of the corresponding linear differential operator, you should pick up any textbook on Sturm-Liouville problem.